What is BaseDefinition and ContentType in visual studio extension development
I have been looking into this example Walkthrough: Customize the text view
In this example, the content type is text as shown here.
[Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]
internal class TestViewCreationListener : IWpfTextViewCreationListener

Mine is a CSharp file, so I tried changing from text to code. But did not work, not sure why.
In various examples on github I have seen, different types.
For example this Ook example uses code
This Diff Classifier example uses text
And in the same file, you can see diff as well if you scroll down a bit(line 30).
So when to use what? What are the different values that this can take? Any arbitrary string value?
Am trying to understand Link a content type to a file name extension example
A quick search on github showed many different things.
Like here I saw intellisence, json here, html here and so on.
So what are the sensible values for BaseDefinition and ContentType?
And what does BaseDefinitionAttribute represent in the first place?
The pain is documentation is very poor, you can see it here for ContentTypes.

BaseDefinitionAttribute is the name of the content type from which this content type is derived. Content types are the definitions of the kinds of text handled by the editor, for example, "text", "code", or "CSharp". This document may help.
